# iOS Realm List as Set or Array equality

Tags: ios, realm, realm-list

I ran into a strange case where I compare a realm list converted to `Set` with another `Set` which they have the same realm object which in its turn override `isEqual` function.
Using `Set` will return `false`! But when I convert both of them into an `Array` it returns `true`.

Here is my code for using both `Set` and `Array`:

```
func equal(lhs: Itemization, rhs: Itemization) -> Bool {
    let discountChanged = lhs.discounts.count == rhs.discounts.count && Set(lhs.discounts) == Set(rhs.discounts)
    return discountChanged // false
}

func equal(lhs: Itemization, rhs: Itemization) -> Bool {
    let discountChanged = lhs.discounts.count == rhs.discounts.count && Array(lhs.discounts) == Array(rhs.discounts)
    return discountChanged // true
}
```

My realm classes:

```
final class Itemization: Object, Mappable {
.....
let discounts = List<AppliedDiscount>()

override func isEqual(_ object: Any?) -> Bool {
        if self === (object as? Itemization) { return true }
        if object == nil { return false }
        if let object = object as? Itemization {
            return equal(lhs: self, rhs: object)
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
}

final class AppliedDiscount: Object {
    dynamic var id: String = ""

    override func isEqual(_ object: Any?) -> Bool {
        if self === (object as? AppliedDiscount) { return true }
        if object == nil { return false }
        if let object = object as? AppliedDiscount {
            return self.id == object.id
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

I am just trying to figure out what is going on.

Comment: Please also show your `Itemization` class declaration, especially its conformance to `Hashable`.

Comment: @DávidPásztor done, it overrides `isEqual` directly, I was using the `==` but it turns out it's not called like in `contains` function

Comment: @MohamMadSalah You should probably also override `hash`. Realm's default implementation returns the same hash only if the primary key is defined and has the same primary key. If the hash is different, `isEqual` isn't called.